# Autofac [WithKey] on PropertyInjection

Tags: autofac

How do I resolve a keyed instance with Property injection in Autofac?

```
builder.RegisterType<ClassA>.As<IService>().Keyed<IService>("serviceA");
builder.RegisterType<ClassB>.As<IService>().Keyed<IService>("serviceB");
```

Using the Autofac.Extras.Attributed lib I try to the following

```
public class OtherService {

    [WithKey("serviceA")]       
    public IService service {set; private get;}

}
```

I have only seen examples where [WithKey] works with Constructor parameters but it seems awkward that Property injection. Am I missing something or is it not supported?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can wire components inside Activated event handler as below:

```
builder
.Register<OtherService>()
.OnActivated(e => e.Instance.Service = e.Context.ResolveKeyed<IService>("serviceA"));
```

You wouldn't want to introduce explicit infrastructure dependency like Autofac inside your services by using WithKey attribute.

Code above assumes that OtherService.Service property setter is public. If private setter is absolutely required it can be set using Reflection API.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, attribute filters only work on constructor parameters.

In fact, the `WithKeyAttribute` is marked with `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]` to enforce that so I'm not sure how you marked a property with it and got it to compile. I'll have to check that out.

Comment: Travis. It did not compile but I just thought it was än Odd restriktion. Thanks for a great framework!